# activate speakar of iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone

i want to make a call and activate speaker of iphone programmatically.

can any one tell me , how to activate and deactivate speaker mode of iphone through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to telephone functionality is not available through the SDK. Consider filing a feature request with Apple's Bug Reporter at http://bugreporter.apple.com/